# Invalid property in <set>: "null" in new ArrayList at JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have got a Set of objects. I need to iterate it and add too my new ArrayList that I created at JSP page. But I have got an error

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Invalid property in <set>:  "null"

Here is my code

```
<jsp:useBean id="idList" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
                        <c:forEach items="${car.tape.idSet}" var="item">
                            <c:set target="${idList}" value="${item.id}"/>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <aui:input class="form-check" checked="${idList.contains(1)?'true':''}" inlineLabel="right"
                                   name="name1"
                                   type="checkbox" value="1"
                                   label="Name1"/>
                        <aui:input class="form-check" checked="${idList.contains(2)?'true':''}" inlineLabel="right"
                                   name="name2" type="checkbox" value="2"
                                   label="name2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error

"avax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Invalid property in : "null" "

because of you have not specified any property attribute in

```
<c:set /> something like    
<c:set target="${myclass}" property="attrib" value="somevalue"/>
```

but in your case ArrayList is the bean and you want to set some value in this. pleas try to use the below sample code.
    package com.example

```
public class  ArrayListBean {

private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setList(Object object) {
    list.add(object);
}

public List<Object> getList() {
    return list;
}
}
```

After that just modify your code like :

```
<jsp:useBean id="idList" class="com.example.ArrayListBean"/>
  <c:forEach items="${car.tape.idSet}" var="item">
     <c:set target="${idList}" property="list" value="${item.id}" />
  </c:forEach>
<aui:input class="form-check" checked="${idList.contains(1)?'true':''}" inlineLabel="right" name="name1" type="checkbox" value="1 label="Name1"/>
<aui:input class="form-check" checked="${idList.contains(2)?'true':''}" inlineLabel="right" name="name2" type="checkbox" value="2" label="name2"/>
```

or

```
<jsp:useBean id="idList" class="com.example.ArrayListBean"/>
  <c:forEach items="${car.tape.idSet}" var="item">
     <jsp:setProperty name="idList" property="list" value="${item.id}" />
  </c:forEach>
<aui:input class="form-check" checked="${idList.contains(1)?'true':''}" inlineLabel="right" name="name1" type="checkbox" value="1 label="Name1"/>
<aui:input class="form-check" checked="${idList.contains(2)?'true':''}" inlineLabel="right" name="name2" type="checkbox" value="2" label="name2"/>

<jsp:setProperty>, This works basically the same way, only the name must refer the bean name, not the bean itself.

<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com.example.Bean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="someProperty" value="newvalue" />
```

It is working fine for me.